# Some inequality; $(\sum a_i^p)^{1/p} \leq C \sum a_i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to know whether or not the following inequality $$
  (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p)^{1/p} \leq C \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$
   is satisfied for some $C$, where $0 \leq a_i,\ 1/2 \leq 1/p$.

For some constant $C$, the above inequality hold ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x =(x_i) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$
\|x\|_p = (\sum |x_i|^p)^{1/p} \text{ and } \|x\|_1 = \sum |x_i|
$$

Consider the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$$
B := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_1 =  1\}
$$
And define $f:B \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = \frac{\|x\|_p}{\|x\|_1}
$$
Check that this function is continuous. Since $B$ is compact, it is bounded by some constant $C>0$. This constant does what you want.